# my ajax request call back whole code page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i just wanna save with button in laravel but when use console log i get whole code in console idk why this happened?

this is my input and button

```
<form action="{{ url('sendcom') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="text" id="editor" name="Name">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" value="Submit">
                    submit
                    </button>

                </form>
```

and i use ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var data = $('#editor').val()
    $.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "{{ route('sendcom') }}",
  data: { data: data },
  success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
  }
});
  });
});

</script>
```

and i get it in controller like this :

```
public function sendcom(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){

            $content = $request->data;

            User::updateOrCreate([
                'contract' => $content
            ]);

            return response(['success' => 'contract save success.']);
        }
    }
```

but when i click on submit button it's get me whole page code
and I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: `$("#btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()` I don't know if that will stop a form posting - usually, one uses the `submit` event to do what you want

Comment: _"i get whole code in console"_ - What code? Please be more specific. Show us what you actually get (or at least a snippet of it so we can understand it better)

Comment: Exactly all the source code show in console when i click on submit `<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(funct` ... `editor5/39.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

</html>
` _@M.Eriksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` keyword here is actually an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Response` which can be seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#response-objects) in the docs. What ajax here is expecting is a `JSON` response which will, as the name implies, be consumed as a javascript object.

The line:

```php
return response(['success' => 'contract save success.']);
```

Should be changed to:

```php
return json_encode(['success' => 'contract save success.']);
```

which will create a new json object to be returned back. We can then access this with `res.success` to get the message.